# Creating a view for the backup status of a SQL Server 2008-2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, view, sql-server-2012, backup

I need to create a view for SQL server for the backup status. The output should look like this:

*DIFF :    0 DAYS

BACKUP DB FULL COMPLETED

START : 2016.01.30 19:48:03

END: 2016.01.30 22:34:51

DURATION 02:46:48

SIZE (GB) :    1,156.77

Backuptype (TSM or SQL Server maintenance plan)

DBNAME*

Any ideas on how to do this for SQL Server? 
Is it possible to identifiy  whether the backup was made with TSM TDP or with SQL Server maintenance plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDB:

```
SELECT
      backup_type =
            CASE f.[type]
                WHEN 'D' THEN 'Full'
                WHEN 'L' THEN 'Log'
                WHEN 'I' THEN 'Diff'
            END
    , f.database_name
    , f.backup_start_date
    , f.backup_finish_date
    , duration = CAST(f.backup_finish_date - f.backup_start_date AS TIME)
    , f.backup_size
    , b.physical_device_name
FROM (
    SELECT
          s.media_set_id
        , s.[type]
        , s.database_name
        , s.backup_start_date
        , s.backup_finish_date
        , backup_size =
            CASE WHEN s.backup_size = s.compressed_backup_size
                THEN s.backup_size
                ELSE s.compressed_backup_size
            END / 1048576.
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.database_name, s.[type] ORDER BY s.backup_finish_date DESC)
    FROM msdb.dbo.backupset s
    --WHERE s.database_name = DB_NAME()
) f
JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily b ON f.media_set_id = b.media_set_id
WHERE f.RowNum = 1
ORDER BY f.backup_finish_date DESC
```

Output -

```
backup_type database_name        backup_start_date    backup_finish_date   duration   backup_size   physical_device_name
----------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------- ------------- ------------------------------------------------------------
Full        model                2016-02-25 15:14:20  2016-02-25 15:14:21  00:00:01   0.52112197    G:\model.bak
Full        kh_sql_server        2016-02-25 13:13:38  2016-02-25 13:13:38  00:00:00   0.53086376    D:\DATABASES\SQL_2012\BACKUP\kh_sql_server.bak
Full        master               2016-02-24 13:27:24  2016-02-24 13:27:26  00:00:02   32.95404911   G:\tempdb.bak
Full        AdventureWorks2012   2016-02-11 13:46:14  2016-02-11 13:46:16  00:00:02   44.70329856   E:\SHARE_BACKUP\AdventureWorks\AdventureWorks2012.bak
Full        Refactoring          2016-01-05 18:59:08  2016-01-05 18:59:10  00:00:02   37.53390598   NUL
Log         shrink_test          2016-01-05 18:56:07  2016-01-05 18:56:07  00:00:00   0.02001571    NUL
Full        shrink_test          2016-01-05 18:49:14  2016-01-05 18:49:14  00:00:00   0.45571231    NUL
Full        backup_test          2015-12-21 14:49:01  2015-12-21 14:49:02  00:00:01   0.45937156    D:\DATABASES\SQL_2012\BACKUP\backup_test.bak
Full        users                2015-11-23 13:15:44  2015-11-23 13:15:45  00:00:01   0.72006702    D:\DATABASES\SQL_2012\BACKUP\users.bak
Full        OnlineFormatFull     2015-11-06 15:08:38  2015-11-06 15:08:39  00:00:01   23.63910865   D:\DATABASES\SQL_2012\BACKUP\T20151106_OnlineFormatFull.bak
```

Default Trace:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN t.EventSubClass = 1
        THEN 'BACKUP' 
        ELSE 'RESTORE'
    END, t.TextData, t.ApplicationName, t.LoginName, t.StartTime, t.EndTime
FROM sys.traces i
CROSS APPLY sys.fn_trace_gettable([path], DEFAULT) t
WHERE i.is_default = 1
    AND t.EventClass = 115 -- Audit Backup/Restore Event
```

Comment: Thank you, TSM TDP backups are shown in the physical_dive_name colume as follows: TDPSQL-000014A0-0000

Comment: It's just a coincidence ;)))